# Why does the Zomato API have issues searching by zipcode?

Tags: zomato-api

Inside of Zomato's API documentation, you can utilize the q parameter to input practically anything. With the url below, I have been testing this with zipcodes in my area and it works like a charm.

However, when I venture out and search zipcodes from different states, it finds no results. Now the weird thing is, if I go on Zomato.com and start trying to find restaurants in their website within those different states and return back to my api call, it starts to work with those zipcodes and no longer with zipcodes from my area! What's the deal? Is there like a cookies issue or something. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

API CALL
https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/search?q= + zipcode + &apikey=[API-KEY]

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround solution that should help anyone else who runs into this issue. I extracted the lat/lon coordinates from the Google Maps API based on the zip code typed in, and then I ran those lat/lon coordinates through the Zomato API. It's one extra step, but it definitely prevents the Zomato API from having geographic restrictions.